# How to extract the Muxer part of FFMpeg

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, muxer

I've build a encoder based on the sample of QUALCOMM, which captures the video and compresses it into h264 file. I am using Android 4.2.2. Now I want to muxer this file into mp4(only video, no audio).

I heard the FFMpeg can do the job. But after I read the example, I found out that the muxer was using the encoder of FFMpeg. I don't know how to use the muxer part on another encoder.

Can anyone give me a hint?
Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to search google for "mp4 library"

Comment: Thanks. I've done some research about this, so I decide to use FFMpeg.